# Is it possible to define examples for individual `Model` or `Serializer` fields with DRF-Spectacular?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-spectacular

I use DRF-Spectacular to generate the OpenAPI specification for my DRF-based API. So far, I do not add examples but instead rely on SwaggerUI to show examples based on the type and regex patterns.

However, in same cases, I would like to add examples directly to the `openapi.yml` file. I would like to define examples for individual `Model` or `Serializer` fields, similar to generating `descriptions` based on the `help_text` parameters.

Unfortunately, so far I've only found ways to defining complete examples for views and serializers based on [`OpenApiExample`](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html?highlight=OpenApiExample#drf_spectacular.utils.OpenApiExample) with [`extend_schema`](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html?highlight=OpenApiExample#customization-by-using-extend-schema) and [`extend_schema_serializer`](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#step-4-extend-schema-serializer), respectively.

This leads me to my question: **Is it possible to define examples for individual `Model` or `Serializer` fields with DRF-Spectacular and, if yes, how?**

Comment: What kind of examples do you want to add to the fields? Is it a set of predefined choices? Or simply any data of a specific type?

Comment: For example, if I have a `CharField` `FirstName`, I would like to add an example `Homer`. Or if we have a `UserId` field, I would like to add an example in addition to the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had trouble with this at first too.

Here's an example for a path parameter:

```
@extend_schema_view(
    retrieve=extend_schema(
        description='Return a given dataset',
        parameters=[
            OpenApiParameter(
                name='slug',
                description='The slug of the dataset to retrieve.',
                examples=[
                    OpenApiExample('Example dataset slug', value='GSE102725')
                ],
                required=True,
                type=OpenApiTypes.STR,
                location=OpenApiParameter.PATH
            )
        ],
        responses={
            200: DatasetSerializer(many=False),
        },
    )
)
```